# Determine DOM element creator?

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend

I'm trying to debug a web page hosting front-end code from multiple vendors. What I'm trying to do is to understand what script creates a specific element in the page. Is there a debugging tool that would let me do that (trace the origins of a DOM element)? I wasn't able to find such functionality in the common debugging tools (Chrome, etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome -> Tools -> Developer Tools

Firefox -> Firebug Plug-In

IE -> F12 Developer Tools

There is a Console tab for JavaScript execution, or Network tab to see when the JS file is loaded or AJAX call is made. You can also search the DOM and do many other things. I found Firebug a little better to see source with AJAX calls.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for responding, Beau! I was looking for something more specific - to identify what object inserted another object into the DOM. I couldn't find such functionality in developer tools.

Comment: If it's an AJAX call then use the network tab, you can see the requests/responses from the calls and is usually HTML, XML or JSON. From there you should be able to find the data/html being inserted into the page.

Comment: If you're able to put an event listener on the element it might help to see when the change is being made or look at the generated CSS to see where the style is coming from on the element. It might at least help you narrow down the vendor.